# How to echo some text inside a for-loop only once?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have this piece of code

```
<?php for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($list["tags"]); $i++) {                    
    if ($list["tags"][$i]["title"]=='list') {
        echo 'Not correct type';
    }
    if ($list["tags"][$i]["title"]!='list') { 
?>

    <a href="...">Text</a>

<?php } 
    } 
?>
```

My problem is that when `$list["tags"][$i]["title"]=='list'`, I get the message 'Not correct type' many times as the loop continues. How can I echo that message only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just have to keep track of whether you've already shown it or not:

```
$shown = false;
for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $list['tags'] ); $i++ ) { 
    if ( $list['tags'][$i]['title'] == "list" && !$shown ) {
        echo "Not correct type";
        $shown = true;
    }
    if ( $list['tags'][$i]['title'] != "list" ) {
        echo '<a href="...">Text</a>';
    } 
}
```

But this raises the question: why would you only want the message to show once? Wouldn't you want it to display "Not correct type" for all values of `$i` for which the title is not `"list"`?

Comment: You are right about that, but the array is built in such a way that if the first title is 'list', then all next titles will be 'list' too. Thanx for the answer. It works great!

Answer (score 2):

You can insert `break;` after the echo statement to exit the loop when the condition is met. Use `break n;` to exit out of *n* layers of loops/conditionals.